# Does anyone know how to get Expedia's customer service to work with me?

Tags: bookings, airlines, expedia

Good morning,

Yesterday I went through Expedia to purchase international airfare. I had been watching flight prices on Google Flights for a few months and was waiting for the roughly six month out point, as most websites say that is the best time to purchase. Google suggested Expedia as they were slightly cheaper than going with Norse Atlantic Airways itself, so I did that. When I hit purchase on the flight confirmation page it did its "I'm thinking" thing and after a minute it errored out and said that the transaction could not be completed. However less than a minute later I had an email from Norse with a link to manage my flight. I was rather confused, so I found the number to call Expedia and asked what was going on. Expedia claims that they cancelled my purchase due to an error in their system and that the transaction would be reversed in a few days. I checked with my credit card and with Norse and both of them insist that the purchase went through and that my reservation on the flight is real. As such I called Expedia back and tried to get more information. They ended up agreeing that if the tickets still existed 24 hours later that I should call back once again.

It's been about 21 hours and the tickets still exist on Norse's website, and my CC shows the flight purchase is pending still. Should I contact Expedia and fight with their customer service folks or continue to wait?

Comment: Banking systems can be extremely slow at processing refunds, I wouldn't take the card as face value. And the question is, do you want the flight or not?

Comment: "They ended up agreeing that if the tickets still existed 24 hours later that I should call back once again" and then "It's been about 21 hours and the tickets still exist". So, wait another three hours and then call them back, right? What am I missing here, why do you say you will need to "fight" them if they already told you that if the tickets are still there now (it's been 3h since you posted) you should call back?

Comment: Personal opinion: Don't use Expedia, their customer service is appallingly bad. Last year I was unable to get a refund from Expedia despite getting the hotel in question to ask Expedia to refund me. Expedia flat out lied to me (claimed they couldn't refund because the hotel didn't agree), ended up having to reverse the credit card charges through my bank.

Comment: Expedia is one of the least bad online travel agencies and I still wouldn't touch them with a barge pole.